# Is there a limit for number of projects you can have in Visual Studio Team Services for free?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there projects number limitation in free Visual Studio Team Services?
It will be appreciate if you describe more about limitation of free Visual Studio Team Services.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a limit of 300 projects within an Azure DevOps Organization according to the [Cloud Migration Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/):

> Project Limits Customers with a large numbers of projects in a collection should note that Azure DevOps Services has a limit of 300 projects per organization. Above 300 projects certain experiences, such as connecting to the organization from Visual Studio, start to degrade. If your collection has more than 300 projects then you will either need to split the collection or delete older projects to get below the limit.

<strike>Every Visual Studio Team Services account is allowed an unlimited number of team projects, private repos, work items, test plans, etc.</strike>  The only charges are if you have more than 5 users, if you need Advanced features for a user, or if you use any of the shared services like the Cloud Build Service, the Cloud Load Testing Service, or Application Insights (in the future).

Comment: the limit of 300 from the Cloud Migration Guide must be taken into consideration.That is actually a limit

Answer (score 3):

According to the Microsoft [TFS to VSTS Cloud Migration guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/), there is a limit of 300 projects per VSTS account:

**Project Limits**

Customers with a large numbers of projects in a collection should note that VSTS has a limit of 300 projects per account. Above 300 projects certain experiences, such as connecting to the account from Visual Studio, start to degrade.