# TFS 2018 Limitations

Tags: tfs

I've been looking for some details about Team Foundation Server 2018:

a) How many projects can I have for collection (maximum) ?

b) Is Power Tools 2015 totally compatible with TFS 2018?

Now I've been trying to find out something related to this 2 topics in the Microsoft Documentation which is important to me.

Concerning this 2 question can anyone point me in the right direction? Because I cannot find the right documentation for this.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a soft limit of about 300 projects per collection (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0923822-80ce-450c-ad2a-5a22aa09e301/is-there-any-limits-on-the-max-number-of-collection-and-team-project-in-tfs2012?forum=tfsgeneral). As for "totally compatible", that's unlikely to be the case. Are there any **specific** concerns you have about individual parts of the Power Tools?

Comment: That Post is old and it's for TFS 2012. I wanted to know if in TFS 2018 we still have Project limitations inside each collection.

Comment: Without more recent information to go off of, that's the best information available. Current guidance is to minimize the number of team projects you have and instead use teams to subdivide a project across team boundaries.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some information available in Microsoft documentation. But I couldn't found it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit for number of projects you can have in Visual Studio Team Services for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329840/is-there-a-limit-for-number-of-projects-you-can-have-in-visual-studio-team-servi)

Comment: Do you really think this is a duplicate? If you think so can you answer my question? If it's a duplicate than the answer should be in the original post...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are wanting.  You asked how many projects you can have.  The linked dupe is asking is there a limit on projects.  The linked answer says 300 and links to the Microsoft documentation which I just checked is still there and was last updated March 2019.  I'm not going to answer this question because it has already been answered on the other question.

Answer (score 3):

*a) How many projects can I have for collection (maximum) ?*

As comment mentioned clearly, currently there isn’t any official document to be referenced for the team project limits in TFS 2018.

Below is the recommended limit for Team Projects and Team Project Collections in TFS 2010, and you can refer to the numbers for your TFS structure.

> 200 Team Projects per Team Project Collection 50 – 200 Active Team
>   Project Collections per SQL Instance (range for 8GB – 64Gb of RAM)
>   From [Martin's blog](https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/), there is a soft limit of about 300 Team
>   Projects per Team Project Collection in TFS 2012.
>
> You can also reference the old document for the limits: [Team
>   Foundation Server Team Project Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa974183(v=vs.80))

---

*b) Is Power Tools 2015 totally compatible with TFS 2018?*

There is no set of TFS 2017 Power Tools/Visual Studio 2017. Since from the [TFS 2017 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#there-are-no-power-tools-for-team-foundation-server-2017).

No Power Tools have been released for TFS 2017. Most of the previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2017, same with TFS 2018.

You could still use Power Tolls 2015, it's not related to TFS version. It's also compatibility with TFS 2018

> Compatibility
>
> You need to match the version of the TFS Power Tools with your Visual
>   Studio client. If you have VS 2015 installed, you need to install the
>   TFS 2015 power tools. **Regardless of which version of TFS you are
>   targeting.**
>
> *[Source Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)*

Comment: 1- You mean 300 projects in TFS 2018? I've found this in your documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa974183(v=vs.80)
Reading this gave me the ideia that for each collection I can have as many projects as I want, although for CMMI templates after 300 it's excessive. For Agile templates after 550 it's excessive and for custom templates after 400 projects it's excessive. Do you agree?

2- SO if I use Visual Studio 2017 which PowerTools do you recommend? Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 right?

Comment: @fr0zt  2.There is not any Power Tools with Visual Studio 2017 at present.We are excited to let you know that most of the previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2018. The Process Template Editor is one that has not been integrated, but we use  this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor instead. For some other tfpt command, there had been a uservoice here but closed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365649/restore-missing-tfs-power-tools-functionality-in-v.html

Comment: @fr0zt 1,almost agree. But indeed it's an old doc. We couldn't guarantee everything is suitable for the latest TFS version. However, we haven't encounter any problem caused by the limitation of projects. If you do in the future, you could directly contact our  support. They will be glad to help you working on this.